# what's the difference between sand and quartz?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

What's the difference between sand and quartz? 
Is quartz more crystalline form of sand? Do they have the same composition or my be not? or my be the two words is similar? Do they contain more than silica?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is very easily Googled.

Comment: atleast you gave a reason for the thumbs down, I h8 it when they dont give a reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Sand is a poorly-defined *mixture*, not a necessarily a pure substance. Some sands are fairly pure $\ce{SiO2}$, the same *chemical formula* as pure quartz, but in some areas of the world, sand can be made of entirely different chemicals, such as calcite.
2. [Quartz is a particular crystal form of $\ce{SiO2}$](http://www.azom.com/article.aspx?ArticleID=1114), but $\ce{SiO2}$ also forms the minerals tridymite, cristobalite, coesite, and stishovite, amorphous silica, etc. It's like having a collection of Legos or TinkerToys that have the same pieces, but can be assembled in different formats.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the informative explanation, so quartz is only one compound (silica) and sand contain more than one compound not only silica

Comment: Possibly... some sands *are* reasonably pure SiO2, others are fairly random mixtures.

Answer (score -1):

quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand)

> The composition of sand varies, depending on the local rock sources and conditions, but the most common constituent of sand in inland continental settings and non-tropical coastal settings is silica (silicon dioxide, or SiO2), usually in the form of quartz.

Sand is a heterogeneous mixture

Quartz is compound

Comment: You might want to expand on this - it's a borderline HW question and your answer should at least include the relevant text from the Wikipedia entry for quartz (and not just the one for sand).

Comment: I think you can do a better job, shall you?

Comment: I can certainly spell better - editing your answer now.

Comment: you converted my ego into a heterogeneous mixture